# execl and wget command in a loop

Tags: c, linux, segmentation-fault

I have edited my previous question.

As I had got the problem and the changed the code, now I have a different problem. If I use execle command, it only downloads one image using the wget command, otherwise it prints all the image names on the screen if the wget command does not execute. I do not understand when there is a while loop, then why does it only print one image.

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<limits.h>
#include<fcntl.h>
#include<sys/stat.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<stdio.h>

void main(int argc, char*argv[])
{
int iFlag;
char cline[100];
FILE*fil = fopen("index.html","rt");
if(fil==NULL)
{
    printf("Error in opening file");
}
char*tmpLine;
char*tok;
const char check[10] = "<img";
const char check2[10] = "src=";
char images[50];
strcpy(images,argv[1]);
while(fgets(cline,100,fil)!=NULL)
{
    if(strstr(cline,check)!=NULL)
    {
        tmpLine=strstr(cline,check);
        if(strstr(cline,check2)!=NULL)
        {
            tmpLine=strstr(cline,check2);
            tok = strtok(tmpLine,"\"");
            while(tok!=NULL)
            {
                tok = strtok(NULL,"\"");
                if(tok[0]!='/')
                {
                    strcat(images,"/");
                    strcat(images,tok);
                    printf("\nimage: %s\n",images);
                    iFlag = execle("/usr/bin/wget","wget","-o","logfile",images,NULL);
                    if(iFlag<0)
                      perror("EXECLE ERROR");
                    break;
                }
                else
                    break;
            }
            memset(&images[0], 50, sizeof(images));
            strcpy(images,argv[1]);
        }
    }

}
```

}

Comment: You should use a debugger. Due to buffering, `printf` are not reliable to spot position of segfault.

Comment: Did you check that `fil` is not NULL?

Comment: If you want to write out debugging stuff, use `fprintf(stderr, ....)`, that isn't buffered and has a better chance of getting seen.

Answer (score 8):

`fil` is probably NULL. Why?

```
FILE*fil = fopen("index.hmtl","rt");
```

Because you typo-ed the filename. This is why checking for errors is a good idea.

Comment: Nice catch ... ;-) and another nice example why one shall **always** check the outcome of system calls. Human error is unpredictable ...

Comment: It appears that I had made a mistake in specifying the file name and consequently, it was returning NULL.

Answer (score 4):

This line

```
        printf("%s\n",tok[0]);
```

does not make sense, as you pass a `char` where are `char *` is expected.

Either do

```
        printf("%s\n", tok);
```

or

```
        printf("%c\n", tok[0]);
```

---

Also this line

```
  char*images = (char*)malloc(100);
```

creates a memory leak, as the reference to the memory allocated to `images` is lost when leaving the context `images` is declared in without having `free()`ed it.

---

Also^2 :

[In C there is no need to cast the result of `malloc/calloc/realloc`, nor is it recommended.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/694576)

So the above line should just better be:

```
char * images = malloc(100);
```

---

Also^3: Always check the outcome of system calls, at least if the code relies on the values returned. Here: Check if `fopen()` failed, as on error `NULL` is returned, which will make the program choke if used as a valid file-pointer.

---

As a general advise on how to find a bug: Compile the code in question using symbols (option `-g` for gcc), then step through the "running" code using a debugger as gcc.

Comment: While correct, this is not the place where the OP is having problem for this question (probably next one would be about that...)

Comment: What would be your suggestion for the usage of:

      char*images = (char*)malloc(100);

because I need a char array in which I can put the url of the webpage and then concatenate the image name that I get from the file and download the image from that link. Every time, I only need to have the main url of the webpage so that I can concatenate the image name.

Comment: @user2507775: This stringly depends on wat you wnat to do with the content of `images`.

Comment: @alk: I need to download those images after that. These images will be sent to a child process through a pipe and the child shall download them to a specified directory.

Answer (score 1):

1. you should check the return value of `fopen()`, as others already pointed it out.
2. `printf("%s\n",tok[0]);` should be `printf("%s\n",tok);`, if you want to print a string.
3. more serious,

   ```
       while(tok!=NULL)
       {
           strcat(images,tok);
       }
       tok = strtok(NULL,quote);
   ```

   this `tok = strtok(...);` should be put inside that `while` loop, otherwise that `tok` will never be changed, and your program will crash finally.